# Get query syntax for a LINQ query

Tags: linq

I have a linq query that i'd like to get the query syntax for.

```
var q = customers.Where(x => x.name == "smith");
```

Is there something like IQueryable.ToQuerySyntaxString()?  that would return something like this:

> from cust in customers where cust.name
>   == "smith";

I'm asking because I can construct my query using method syntax, but would like to see the query syntax equivalent to help me learn how to write in the alternate form.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You've provided some code, but not really said what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hopefully that's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works the other way around.  When you use the second syntax (`from x in y where w`), it actually gets compiled into the first (`y.Where(x => w)`).

I'm sure you could write something to produce the second version using Expression Trees, but I'm not aware of anything in the framework that will do it automatically for you.

Comment: Not the anwser I was hoping for. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

try re-linq from relinq.codeplex.com

```
new QueryParser ().GetParsedQuery (q.Expression).ToString()
```

will give you just that.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper will often allow you do that. It can suggest converting from for/foreach to LINQ as well as LINQ back to loops (see http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/whatsnew_60.html#LINQtoLoops for the latter), plus LINQ method chains to/from query syntax.